# How does pskill work across the UAC/elevation boundary?

Tags: windows, uac, kill-process, sysinternals

Disclaimer: I'm asking specifically on Stackoverflow because I want to know how to re-implement this feature.

We recently noticed that the Sysinternals tool [`pskill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/pskill) can kill an *elevated* process from a non-elevated context.

Specifically, if *you* open a program with Run-As-Administrator and then run a normal shell (non-elevated) and try to kill that RunAs programm (e.g. another cmd.exe) via `pskill`, **it will succeed**.

Note: Both Powershell `Stop-Process` and the `taskkill.exe` utility *cannot* do this.

Killing Windows Services running as NT-Auth/System ~ Session 0 still gives access denied from a non-elevated context though, even with pskill, which is fine.

Which Windows API is used here? Our tooling uses `OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS...` and `TerminateProcess` but this only works on the same elevation level.

Comment: Debug it and set a breakpoint on OpenProcess?

Comment: Debug with http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor / OpenProcess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

really nothing strange. pskill try open process with `PROCESS_TERMINATE|SYNCHRONIZE` access. which is ok. by default elevated process grant

`PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` to `BUILTIN\Administrators` (*S-1-5-32-544*) and `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` (*S-1-5-18*)

and `SYNCHRONIZE|READ_CONTROL|PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION|PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_READ|PROCESS_TERMINATE` for the LogonSession sid (*S-1-5-5-0-ID*)

also mandatory label set for `SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_NO_WRITE_UP | SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_NO_READ_UP` for `Mandatory Label\High Mandatory Level` - this disable all generic read and generic write access for tokens with low integrity level than High. so this label disable `READ_CONTROL|PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_READ` as part of general read access for process. but we still have
`SYNCHRONIZE|PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION|PROCESS_TERMINATE` as maximum access. and this is enough for terminate.

so even if we run as low integrity process, but in the same logon session - we still can kill elevated process

Comment: `SYNCHRONIZE|PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION|PROCESS_TERMINATE` works for me, thanks! ... But I have to skip `READ_CONTROL`: Adding that flag I'll get ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED!

Comment: @MartinBa - you really need only `PROCESS_TERMINATE` access. about `READ_CONTROL` - i was incorrect in the last part of answer. the mandatory label disable all generic read and generic write access to process. so need remove this access from request. the `READ_CONTROL` is part of generic read. i will modify answer

Comment: thank for the additional info. I personally also "need" SYNC, because I want to wait for the process handle after I issue TerminateProcess. But good to know.

Comment: @MartinBa - you can open process with `SYNCHRONIZE|PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION|PROCESS_TERMINATE` from the same logon session.

Comment: DACL give `SYNCHRONIZE|READ_CONTROL|PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION|PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_READ|PROCESS_TERMINATE` for the logon session sid and label remove `READ_CONTROL|PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_READ` from this